# gnu_cxx::hash_map is behaving strangely

Tags: c++, gdb

I am trying to find an element in a gnu_cxx::hash_map that is keyed by strings. The string I am searching is "\xofiller!fill!1_620200 " (thereis only 1 backslash at the beginning. 
The element is not found. So inside gdb I change the search key to "xofiller!fill!1_620200 " and the element is found but oddly the key of the pair found is the original on. "\xofiller!fill!1_620200 ". I am using std::equal_to which is really ==.
I experimented and I can lose a few characters at the end as well. I am starting to suspect that GDB is misleading me. Is there something special about a backslash at the beginning?
Thanks
Danny

Comment: `\x` precedes the hex value for the character you want, but `o` isn't a valid hex digit, so I don't know. Clang gives me an error when using that as a string literal, in fact.

Comment: You typed two backslashes in the source code to get a backslash in the string, right?

Comment: Yes I typed two backslashes. Thanks.